# cannot identify this mxml construct

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

This is making me a little crazy.  I have the following in an mxml file:

```
  <mx:Image source="img/{XML(data).foo}{XML(data).bar}.png" height="21" width="21"/>
```

foo and bar are tags defined in my xml file.

What the heck is "XML(data)"?  Is it a function or a notation or something else?  I've been trying to google it but searching on:  flex "XML(" gives me all kinds of stuff I don't want.

is there an alternate name for whatever this is?

Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any additional information or context, I would say the intent of that snippet was to type cast a generic Object (data) to a fully qualified XML class.

More info on type casting can be found here:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f87.html

Comment: I believe this answer is correct.  +1 for giving that without seeing the code in the original post--which was not formatted properly, and thus was hidden.